# Pass value to a stored procedure in ms sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is how I get the value of the selected column in a gridview in my code behind(C#)

```
str += "'" + MyGridview.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + "',";
```

This is the value of str

```
str='7','101','235','456'
```

My output here is correct.  My problem is i got error when i pass this value on stored procedure parameter.

This is the way I pass this value to my stored procedure;

```
: some other parameter here
cmD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rec",str);
```

And on my stored procedure this is how i get this

```
Declare @Rec AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

Select col1,col2 where Record_no in ('' + @Rec + '')
```

My error is

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value
```

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `str` you are passing to the stored proc?

Comment: show me your stored proc.